# select query using getdate() to after 15 days in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
name   amount  date
---------------------------------------
xxx     1000   2014-04-20 12:53:23.983
yyy     1500   2014-04-25 12:53:23.983
```

My output like this:

```
name  amount  date
--------------------------------------
xxx     1000  2014-04-20 12:53:23.983
```

My query:

```
alter proc K_VM_GetTaxdetails
as
begin
   select name, amount, date 
   from K_VM_TaxDetails
   where DATEADD(day, -15, GETDATE()) = date 
end
```

I have tried like this but I am not getting required output.

If I have a date = 2014-04-20 12:53:23.983 in my table, I want to display all data before 15 days from that date.

How can I write in where condition?

Comment: As I understand you want to output dates that are 15 days before the dates you have in the table. If yes, please move dateadd into the select part of the query and no need for where: 
select name,amount,DATEADD(day, -15, date) from K_VM_TaxDetails

Comment: yes but i want to show actual date only

Answer (score 1):

This displays all rows in the last 15 days:

```
declare @now = select cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float)) as datetime); -- truncate time from datetime

select name, amount, date from K_VM_TaxDetails 
       where date >= dateadd(day, -15, @now);
```

This displays all rows for single day 15 days ago:

```
declare @now = select cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float)) as datetime); -- truncate time from datetime

select name,amount,date from K_VM_TaxDetails 
       where date >= dateadd(day, -15, @now) and 
             date <  dateadd(day, -14, @now);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all data from the day 15 days ago

```
alter proc K_VM_GetTaxdetails
as
begin
   declare @d datetime = dateadd(day, datediff(day, -15, getdate()), 0)
   select name, amount, date 
   from K_VM_TaxDetails
   where date >= @d -- retrieve from
         and date < dateadd(day, 1, @d) -- retrieve to
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Shows dates at least 15 days older than the current date:

```
select name,amount,date from K_VM_TaxDetails
where  date <= DATEADD(day, -15, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to compare date with only date part and not time as including time in date comparison sometimes provided incorrect result.

Below query removes time part and compare only date.

```
select name, amount, date 
   from K_VM_TaxDetails
   where (convert(date,[date]) >= DATEADD(day, -15, convert(date,GETDATE())) and convert(date,[date]) <= convert(date,GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alter proc K_VM_GetTaxdetails
as
begin
   select name, amount, date 
   from K_VM_TaxDetails
   where DATEADD(day, -15, SYSDATETIME()) = date 
end
```